# How get and set work inside a Construction Function?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, constructor

this is the question that I got: Use the class keyword to create a Thermostat class. The constructor accepts a Fahrenheit temperature.
In the class, create a getter to obtain the temperature in Celsius and a setter to set the temperature in Celsius.
Remember that C = 5/9 * (F - 32) and F = C * 9.0 / 5 + 32, where F is the value of temperature in Fahrenheit, and C is the value of the same temperature in Celsius.

the code below is the answer, **can you explain why do I need that set to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit? cause I only have to output Celsius, not Fahrenheit**

```
class Thermostat {
  constructor(fahrenheit) {
    this.fahrenheit = fahrenheit;
  }
  
  get temperature() {
    return (5 / 9) * (this.fahrenheit - 32);
  }
  
  set temperature(celsius) {
    this.fahrenheit = (celsius * 9.0) / 5 + 32;
  }
}
const thermos = new Thermostat(76); // Setting in Fahrenheit scale
let temp = thermos.temperature; // 24.44 in Celsius
thermos.temperature = 26;
temp = thermos.temperature; // 26 in Celsius
```

Comment: The assignment specifies that the temperature is stored in Fahrenheit and the constructor accepts Fahrenheit and `get temperature()` assumes this as well. So you need to do the conversion. You would probably do it differently in real life and just store Celsius.

Comment: "*can you explain why do I need that set to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit?*" you wrote the code, And you're setting `temperature`. If you don't set `temperature` no need for a setter.

Comment: @VLAZ I didn't write it, it's the answer from free code camp

Comment: In that case, they are setting `termperature`. If you don't set `temperature` no need for a setter.

Comment: @Mark I got what you say. Thank you for solving my problem

Comment: @VLAZ I got it. Thank you so much